# click on color changes - boolean

Tags: javascript

why the first click must to equal to false. if i switch it to  true, it does not work.
and why when i clicked, it goes to the else statement first, turns to yellow even when i tried with click= !click at end.
is it fine not to give a value to the click?

```
     var button = document.querySelector("button");
     var click;

     button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (click){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        click=false;
      }else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    click=true;
      }


    });
```

Comment: Declaring a variable `var click;` without defining it will be `false` so `if (click) {...` statement is saying: `if (false) {...`

Answer (score 1):

Some initial values of dataTypes:

```
int => 0
string => null
boolean => false
```

That's why when you declare variable in JavaScript and use as Boolean, it will return `false`;

```js
var b; // initial value is false
if(b){ // if(false) => ...going to else block
 console.log(true);
}else{
 console.log(false);
}
```

If you want Boolean to be true then you have to assign `true`:

```
var b = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Yellow color in css which is without click.
Change the color to pink when the button is clicked by the following way.

```
  body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

<button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';">Change Color</button>
```

I hope you are doing this

Comment: my question is  why  Click=false, has to appear at if else statement first , why not click=true. once i switch them, it would not work

Comment: you have considered click as variable and also using eventlistener click.so give some value to var click either true or false . var click=true or var click=false

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not initialize the value of click. So the value of click is undefined. So why  if (click) is false and execution is going else block. You have declare  click=true in else block so why it will execute if(click) on second click.